# Access the NXT / Ardor database console?

Tags: nxt, database

I want to do some queries on the H2 database. How can I access this console that lets me type in commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the NXT's H2 database from the website by going to /dbshell path.

**Example:** 
Show top 100 accounts sorted by balance:

> select *, BALANCE / 100000000 as NXT from account where latest = true
>   order by balance desc limit 100